# Ansible not looking for modules in ./library alongside playbook

Tags: ansible

In the ansible documentation [intro_configuration](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#library) it is said that:

> Ansible ... it also will look for modules in the ”./library”
>     directory alongside a playbook.

Im my case the only way I get that the directive provide by `gaqzi.ssh-config` was seen by ansible was to explicitly export ANSIBLE_LIBRARY with a full path ;(

Without that `gaqzi.ssh-config` module is not found by ansible, regarding the documentation it should.

Here what I have to do to make it work::

```
$ cd playbook   # my folder were the plabooks are
$ ansible-galaxy install -p library gaqzi.ssh-config  # I get a lib
$ export ANSIBLE_LIBRARY=/home/me/full/path/to/the/above/playbook/library
$    # the export above is annoying
```

How can I dynamicaly check the places Ansible is really looking for 'library' ?

PS1: I'm using ansible 2.0 and vagrant 1.8.1::

```
$ vagrant --version
Vagrant 1.8.1
$ ansible --version
ansible 2.0.0.2
config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
$
```

PS2: I took care to remove all ansible.cfg/.ansible.cfg files excepted the one provide by ubuntu in `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg`

Comment: What if you store the module in your roles path? (ie `roles_path`)

Comment: I really would like to help improving the documentation, so I need to be sure that ansible is not doing what is expected to provide an useful bug report.

Comment: I found the same when experimenting with Ansible 2.0.0.2 a while ago. If you're just looking for a solution, mine was to put the modules inside a role. Ansible will look for modules and plugins inside any role in your roles folders, e.g. `roles/foo/library`

Comment: I also did it and downloaded the role. After that copied that role to playbooks/library/foo if it does not pick that module from default installation

Comment: So it seems that what documentation say is not reflected in the code, I just opened this issue on ansible tracker https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/15947

Answer (score 9):

Ansible actually do search in `current_playbook/library` directory.

You can test this with the following setup:

1. Place this `custom_module.py` into `library` subdir:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/python
   import json
   print json.dumps({"hello" : "world"})
   ```
2. Make the following `test.yml` playbook:

   ```
   ---
   - hosts: localhost
     tasks:
       - name: custom module
         custom_module:
   ```
3. Execute `ansible-playbook -vv test.yml`

With `ansible-galaxy` you install **role**, not **module**.
Parameter `-p` for `ansible-galaxy` defines the `ROLE_PATH`.

If you want just a module `ssh_config` from the `gaqzi.ssh-config` role,
you need to copy the `ssh_config.py` from `current_playbook/library/gaqzi.ssh-config/library` into `current_playbook/library`.

Alternatively you can install the `gaqzi.ssh-config` role into `roles` directory, as expected.
Then modify your playbook to apply this role by adding:

```
roles:
  - gaqzi.ssh-config
```

After applying this role, module `ssh_config` will become available in your playbook.

Comment: If you want the module to work with a role, you should put the library folder inside the role folder. I have just confirmed.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can set a role module as a dependency of your role, for example in your meta/main.yml file:

```
---
dependencies:
  - { role: gaqzi.ssh-config }
```

Then you can start using the module in your role.